# PIL Image from numpy array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

*This turned out to be a very specific bug in a pre-7.0 version of PIL. I'm leaving it here because I've seen other hit the same issue and there isn't a good overview of what you see. There is no programming error here - the solution is "upgrade PIL"*

I'm converting a numpy boolean array (ie, a mask) to a `PIL` image, and seeing a very odd behaviour.

```
# using PIL pixel access - works as expected
img = Image.new('1', (100, 100)) # '1' for 1-bit image mode
img_pixels = img.load()

for x in range(1, 99):
    for y in range(1, 50):
        img_pixels[x,y] = True

img
```

[image: PIL Pixel Access version]

```
# Numpy array, turning into a PIL image. 
ary = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.bool)

for x in range(1, 99):
    for y in range(1, 50):
        ary[x,y] = True
      
Image.fromarray(ary)
```

[image: numpy version]

If I inspect the values of `ary` it appears the `True` values are appropriately set.

So why are these images different?

Edit:

If I reverse x and y for the numpy version I get this. It's clear that something else is going on because if it was just rows and columns reversed I should get the same shape but vertically aligned.

```
ary = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.bool)

for x in range(1, 99):
    for y in range(1, 50):
        ary[y,x] = True # note that rows and columns are reversed
      
Image.fromarray(ary)
```

[image: numpy using column,row ordering]

Comment: numpy array uses `[row,col]` which means `[y,x]`

Comment: I've edited to show the image generated using [y,x]

Comment: Side note: you could replace the nested for loops in the last snippet by `ary[1:51, 1:100] = True`

Comment: when I run your code with `[y,x]` then it gives me correct image. When I run with `[x,y]` then it gives me also correct image but rotated 90 degrees. You have to do something else and it makes problem. OR problem is in different place.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem so we don't know why you get different results. You can try to save in file and open in diffferent image vewers. BTW: do you run it in some console or notebook. I had to use `img.show()` to display it.

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/nlothian/0c985ff4beaf0a3fbb0507a24805eb83

Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: And yes, I'm testing in a notebook. Python 3.7.7 on MacOS...

Comment: This is what I get with your code https://gist.github.com/furas/0210ce506e182dfd23c580290dbd382d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in an earlier version of PIL that was fixed by at least version 7.0

With

- PIL: 7.2.0
- numpy: 1.19.1

the behaviour is as expected. Thanks to @furas for his help testing.

Answer (score 1):

PIL has reverse `x` and `y` locations. To fix it, exchange `x` and `y` in your code:

```
ary = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.bool)

for x in range(1, 99):
    for y in range(1, 50):
        ary[y,x] = True
      
Image.fromarray(ary)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. 

I've edited the question to show what happens if you do this, but also if it was as simple as reversing the x and y I'd have the same shape but aligned vertically.

Comment: After some debugging, the scrambled images turned out to be caused by a pre-7.0 version of the PIL library. This answer is correct in that there is also a x,y reversal bug in my code, which is easy to see once the bug-free library version is used!

Comment: @NickLothian Feel free to accept the answer to close the question. Also, as a recommendation for future posts, if there is an answer with **posted desired output**, and you do not get the same output as the post, the best is to try and upgrade the libraries.

Comment: Sorry - I can't accept this answer because it doesn't correctly solve the issue as posted.

Comment: @NickLothian LOL, alright. You can later accept your own answer to close the question anyways.