# Why does Python Pillow swap x and y axis

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I tried this example from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pillow-colors-on-an-image/) where you create a blue picture. And I wanted to try something more out of it, so I wanted to change a single pixel from blue to red. Meanwhile, I did that successfully, I notice that position of the red pixel is reversed. Instead of [1,4] i got [4,1] pixel to turn red, I noticed the same problem of switching x and y with function Image.frombytes. I tried reading [the class(PixelAccess) documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess) but haven't found anything. I am using Python 3.10.6 and 9.2.0 the latest version of PIL which makes this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256952/pil-image-from-numpy-array-indexing) not relevant.

The easiest solution is to switch x and y in code, but I can't find a reason why are they swapped.

```
from PIL import Image
input = Image.new(mode="RGB",size=(10, 10),
                        color="blue")
input.save("input", format="png")
pixel_map = input.load()
pixel_map[1,4] = (255,0,0)
input.save("path\\example.png", format="png")
```

edit:
I have added a red thick red line in the middle.
So regarding this code, the line should vertical, not horizontal like it is

```
// this code goes instead of line:  pixel_map[1,4] = (255,0,0)

i = 0
j = 0
for i in range (10):
    for j in range (10):
        if j == 4 or j == 5:
            pixel_map[i,j] = (255,0,0)
            pixel_map[i,j] = (255,0,0)
```

Comment: I don't get it; the list is in `x, y` format as is the standard; you set pixel `(1, 4)` to blue, meaning that, starting from the top left corner (the origin), the pixel will be shifted one to the right and 4 down. When I run your code that's exactly what I see.; the blue pixel is one to the right and 4 down. X is horizontal, Y is vertical, and `(0, 0)` is the upper left corner. That's a ubiquitous representation of pixels. It would be strange for it to not be that way. Why do you think that the array's format is `Y, X`?

Comment: @RandomDavis Probably because **Numpy** specifies row first, then column.

Comment: Because in programming the x represents the rows and y represents the columns, in maths, it is the other way around. So when I iterate by nested for loops (for x in range 10; for y in range 10), if I want my picture NOT to be inverted I need to iterate [y][x]. I can add some more code to clarify my confusion@RandomDavis

Comment: X is the horizontal component though. It's always been that case. What do you mean it refers to rows in math? It's the vertical component that determines row. Why would iterating via `x, y` make things inverted? If you iterate the way you said, the pixels will iterate left to right, top to bottom, in reading order. Is the confusion just regarding the origin being in the upper left, and the Y values increasing as you go down vertically? People iterating over image pixels don't seem to have a problem with it being in X, Y order. [example](https://predictivehacks.com/iterate-over-image-pixels/)

Comment: @RandomDavis added extra code to clarify my confusion

Comment: Oh got it. So it's just that you're transitioning from thinking of the first index as the row, and the second as the column, when with digital images it's the other way around. Not sure what answers you're looking for; the order is just determined by the tool you are using. Some tools use pixel coordinates (x, y) while others use matrix coordinates (y, x). Matrix coordinates are indeed how images are usually internally stored, but I think the (x, y) order is a layer of "convenience" that is added sometimes. This thread has some related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54549322/6273251

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/PyAccess.py#L136) that actually gets the pixel when accessing the loaded image data, you'll see that it actually indexes `self.pixels[y][x]`. So, internally, it's being stored how you expect; it's just that the pixel access object deliberately chose the index to be in `(x, y)` order. So, do with that info what you will.

Comment: So that means that function accepts [x,y] as it is, but returns them inverted? @RandomDavis

Comment: It means that the PixelAccess object can be indexed via `[x, y]` but internally it stores the pixels as `[y][x]`, so internally it swaps the order. You do not have access to this internal representation as far as I know. That's just an implementation detail anyway; it is in that order when using this particular object in this particular library. I don't know what you mean by "returns them inverted". Unless you mean that the outputted image is "inverted" compared to your expectations of which order the row and column index go in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247527/discussion-between-forthrider-and-random-davis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of my comments:

It is pretty standard to access digital images via `[x, y]` coordinates, as opposed to `[y, x]` or  `[y][x]`. In mathematics, arrays are usually indexed by row and then column, but with images, the width component is conventionally first - hence why we say resolutions like "1920x1080", which is the X and then Y value. And, just like when accessing a cartesian coordinate plane in mathematics, X refers to the horizontal component, and is first, while Y is second and refers to the vertical component. So, images tend to be treated more like a coordinate system than a matrix, at least when a layer of abstraction is added like PIL is doing. **Hence, I think this can be confusing for those who are used to how 2D arrays are typically indexed.**

[Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70673/54866) is a post which does a great job explaining why there's different coordinate systems. It's far more detailed and well-researched than what I'm capable of coming up with right now.

Like I said I think there's just some understandable confusion when it comes to transitioning from thinking of the first index as the row, and the second as the column, when with digital images it's the other way around usually. In the end, the order is just determined by the tool you are using. Some tools use pixel coordinates `(x, y)` while others use matrix coordinates `(y, x)`. Matrix coordinates are indeed how images are usually internally stored, but I think the `(x, y)` order is a layer of "convenience" that is added sometimes. This thread has some related discussion: [why should I use (y,x) instead of (x,y) to access a pixel in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54549322/6273251)

If you look at the [Pillow source code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/main/src/PIL/PyAccess.py#L136) that actually gets the pixel when accessing the loaded image data, you'll see that it actually indexes `self.pixels[y][x]`. So, internally, it's being stored how you expect; it's just that the pixel access object deliberately chose the index to be in `(x, y)` order. The `PixelAccess` object can be indexed via `[x, y]` but internally it stores the pixels as `[y][x]`, so internally it swaps the order. You do not have access to this internal representation as far as I know. That's just an internal implementation detail though.